# Issue with convention-based Route in maproute method asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following route and its action method.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Movies",
    "Movies/{action}/{id}/{Genre}/{myprop}",
    new { controller = "Movies", action = "Random", id=UrlParamter.Optional, Genre=UrlParameter.Optional,myprop = UrlParameter.Optional }
    new { Genre=@"^[a-zA-Z]+$",myprop=@"\d{2}" }
);

public ActionResult Random(string id, string Genre, string myprop)
{
    var movie = new Movie() { Name = "Shrek!" };
    ViewBag.idgm = id + " " + Genre + " " + myprop;
    return View(movie);
}
```

Now when I try to get from this URL:

```
http://localhost:60008/Movies/Random/5/qweqw
```

I get a 404.

But If I try

```
http://localhost:60008/Movies/Random/5/qweqw/23
```

It works. I am not able to understand why this is happening. Can anybody help?

This is my complete map route method:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
       "Movies",
       "Movies/{action}/{id}/{genre}/{myprop}",
       new { controller = "Movies", action = "Random", genre = UrlParameter.Optional, myprop = UrlParameter.Optional },
       new { Genre= @"^[a-zA-Z]+$", myprop=@"\d{2}" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{myid}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", myid = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: With routing the first match always wins. Please show the routes that you are registering *before* the one in your question (including areas and attribute routes)

Comment: Sure I have edited my question and have given the maproute method

Comment: No its a very simple application, I was testing if its possible to create my own parameters in route and apply constraints. No areas were used. I also noticed that I didn't add id as optional and added it, but still I face same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a 404 for the first URL is because the route constraint for `myprop` makes that parameter ***required*** - it only matches a 2 digit number and never an empty string.

```
myprop=@"\d{2}"
```

To fix it, change the regex to match either a 2 digit number **or** an empty string.

```
myprop = @"\d{2}|^$"
```

### Explanation

The `^$` will match a zero length string. The `|` is the regex alteration character (the rough equivalent of a logical OR). The regex must allow an empty string to pass through so the constraint succeeds before it can analyze the value `UrlParameter.Optional`. Effectively, without allowing a zero length string to match the parameter is required because the regex failure happens first.

Reference: [Zero-Length Regex Matches](https://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html)